# git append "Reviewed-by" to commits

Tags: git, rebase

Apparently not the most popular situation, but I have a number of commits to whose messages I want to append a line `Reviewed-by: user<mail>`.

So far I only found this command which fails for me with `Invalid line: 10: Reviewed-by: User <mail>`

```
GIT_EDITOR='git interpret-trailers --trailer "Reviewed-by: User <mail>" --in-place' git rebase -i HEAD~8
```

I also asked on IRC, to no avail.

Any other suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### `git rebase` solution

- For git 2.32 and higher:

  ```bash
  git rebase HEAD~3 -x 'git commit --amend --no-edit --trailer "Reviewed-by: User <email>"'
  ```
- For older versions I had the following solution. It doesn't look perfect, but does its job, and in my sanity-test it doesn't fail e.g. with commit messages that has a single double quote:

  ```bash
  git rebase HEAD~2 -x 'git commit --amend -m"$(git log --format=%B -n1)$(echo -ne \\nReviewed-by: User \<email\>.)"'
  ```

Let's break down the second command *(which is a complicated version of the 1st one)*:

1. `git rebase HEAD~2 -x …` does rebase of n commits *(where n = 2)*, to which you wanted to append `Reviewed-by`, and for every commit it stops and executes the shell command that follows.
2. `git commit --amend -m…` amends the commit, and replaces its message with the one that follows.
3. `git log --format=%B -n1` prints message of the "current" commit.
4. `echo -ne \\nReviewed-by: User \<email\>.` this one is a bit tricky. The obvious part is that it adds the `Reviewed-by` text. The less obvious one is that inline command execution removes trailing whitespace, i.e. the output of the previous command don't have newlines. So `echo` here adds a newline, and then the text.

---

You can use that as is by getting it from command history, or you can wrap it to a bash/zsh function, e.g.:

```bash
# adds reviwed-by to n commits
function git_rb() {
    # export arguments, otherwise they're not visible to inline shell executions
    export who=$1
    export email=$2
    export n=$3
    git rebase HEAD~$n -x 'git commit --amend -m"$(git log --format=%B -n1)$(echo -e \\nReviewed-by: ${who} \<${email}\>.)"'
}
```

and then use it as

```bash
$ git_rb "Holy Moly" "Holy@example.com" 5
```

### `git filter-branch` solution

A bit limited solution that I found in [this article](https://davidwalsh.name/update-git-commit-messages). Turns out, you can use `git filter-branch` to do the same. It prints a warning though that says it can mangle up the history, and recommends to use `git filter-repo` instead. But it's a separate from git project, I didn't test it. From reading "gotchas" I got an impression that for modifying commit messages `git filter-branch` is fine. But one problem I find with this method: you can't use a `HEAD~n` notation, it would bail out with `You must specify a ref to rewrite` error. Instead you have to use a notation like `master..HEAD`, which does limit its usefulness a bit. An example:

```bash
git filter-branch -f --msg-filter 'cat && echo -e "\nReviewed-by: User<Holy Moly>"' master..HEAD
```

Comment: Can you describe a simple use-case? I fail to find one.

Comment: @RomainValeri projects that still use mailing lists *(although ones that recently migrated to gitlab [seems to retain this policy too](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/mesa/mesa/merge_requests/226#note_116213))* often use "reviewed-by", "acked-by", "tested-by", etc. to mark particular commits as reviewed, acknowledged, or tested by someone, accordingly.

Comment: I get that, but rewriting history (which commit message rewriting causes) is not a given on any branch on many workflows. I guess my own workplace workflow and short experience are not enough to grasp the advantages of this, and how it can be applied without creating a branch update nightmare for everyone, but I'm sure it's on me, no worries :-) Thanks for sharing.

Comment: @RomainValeri actually, rewriting history in a developer's branch before merging to upstream is an established workflow. Both on gitlab and github, when you send a pull/merge request to upstream, you need to pass a review. Which requires you to address comments on your work, which in turn is done by rewriting the commits you wanted to merge. As a side note, I myself don't really know reasons specifically for adding R-b, A-b, etc to commits. I vaguely remember reading somewhere that R-b was introduced because of licenses on the work…

Comment: Hmm, a typo, in the last sentence I meant "S-b", not "R-b". "I vaguely remember reading somewhere that S-b was introduced because of licenses on the work…"

Answer (score 5):

Starting with Git 2.32, the commit command itself supports appending trailers to commits, so Hi-Angel's solution can be simplified to

`git rebase HEAD~2 -x "git commit --amend --no-edit --trailer Reviewed-by: "User <Mail>"`

I'd leave this as a comment, but I don't have enough reputation for that.

Comment: Thank you! I modified the solution to now include that way as well